# jQuery.scrollTo is not working in jquery 2.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I upgraded my `jQuery1.6.2` to `jQuery2.1.1.js`. I included `jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js` in my app so that there is no need to change the previous code according to jQuery2.1.1.

Everything works fine but `scrollTo` is not working. I already had `jquery.scrollTo.js` plugin. I used `scrollTo` as

```
$('#wrapper').scrollTo(anchor, 0, {offset:{top:-50, left:-50}});
```

`anchor` is a <div> object.

Any idea of how to use scrollTo in jquery2.1.1?

Comment: do you receive any errors in dev console ?

Comment: I am getting the error in console

  TypeError: val is undefined
attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ?  in jquery.scrollTo.js

Comment: hmmm the scrollTo plugin is supposed to work fine, maybe you have a conflict between jquery 2.1.1 and 1.2.1migrate? can you fiddle the relevant code so i could reproduce the error ?

Comment: Having the same issue, I added "back" jquery.scrollTo and now it works.